# How to keep reference to a child view with Binding inside the parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Inside one parent SwiftUI view, I need to keep reference to a child view which is a UIViewRepresentable. For that, I create an instance of the child view during the parent init, and allocate it to a property. This works quite well.

```
struct parentView: View {
    var childView: ChildView

    init() {
        self.childView = ChildView()
    }

    var body: some View {
        childView
    }
}
```

My issue is when the child view needs some bindings as parameters. As the bindings are not initialized yet, Xcode raise an error. How could I solve that ?

```
struct parentView: View {
    @State private var property1: Bool = false
    var childView: ChildView

    init() {
        self.childView = ChildView(property1: $property1)
    }

    var body: some View {
        childView
    }
}

struct ChildView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var property1: Bool

    // code
}
```

Or may be I’m wrong, and there are other solutions to have direct access to subview’s func than keeping reference of them.

Comment: SwiftUI view is not a reference type, it is struct - value, you cannot keep reference to it.

Comment: Why exactly do you *need to keep reference to a child view*?

Comment: Hi guys, I know SwiftUI is not a reference type, but in some specific case it's still needed. In my case, the UIViewRepresentable is a Mapbox map, and this view has some specific methods not use to setup/draw the view, like one transforming a coordinate in CGPoint. It's used by my parent view to perform some stuffs.

Comment: You should see how you can refactor your code. Separate the view from the model such that views are disposable.

Comment: @Paulw11, I’m not sure how to do that ... have you an idea ?

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for me to provide any more information, but the starting point is to remove any state from views. This sounds like an [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a nice solution in a YouTube video from Kavsoft:

```
struct parentView: View {
    @State private var property1: Bool = false
    var uiView = UIViewClass()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            childView(uiView: $uiView, property1: $property1)
            Button("Direct action to uiView") {
                uiView.action()
                let returnString = uiView.actionReturningString()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var uiView: UIViewClass
    @Binding var property1: Bool

    // UIViewRepresentable protocol
}
```